# Clickable buttons in a tableviews header

Tags: swift, uitableview, uibutton

I have an app where there's a UITableView. I added buttons into the header like this:

```
var header = UIView(frame: .zero)
let text = UILabel(frame: .zero)
text.text = "Recent matchplayers"
text.font = .medium(14)
header.addSubview(text)


let recent = RecentContactsView()
header.addSubview(recent)


self.tableView.tableHeaderView = header
```

(I left out the code for constraints and stuff)

However, the buttons within `RecentContactsView` are not clickable. Is there a way to enable interaction within a table's header?

Comment: are you disabling interaction on the table view (or superviews for that table view)? (because there is no reason why you cannot tap a button if it is part of the tableview header.

Comment: just assign header view frame `(x:0,y:0,width:screenWidht,height:200)`  
 instead of `.zero`

Answer (score 0):

The buttons are not clickable because they are outside the bounds of one of heir superviews. I suspect this is because you are setting a frame of zero for the header view. Your header view’s frame needs to be large enough to cover the buttons so that they can receive touch events.